# Should i delete portrait layout directory if i want only landscape orientation in my app?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want my app to work in landscape only. 
I created an abstract class for extending

```
public void onCreate (Bundle bundle){
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
}
```

Then i created directory res/layout-land for landscape layouts. But i don't know what to do with directory res/layout.

Should i delete that portrait directory "layout" if i want to leave only landscape orientation in my app?
Thank you!

Comment: Short answer: yes, almost certainly. Perhaps move it out and check if things build before deleting  to be on the safe side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than deleting the `layout` directory, if your app supports only landscape, then put your landscape layouts in the `layout` directory, and delete the `layout-land` directory entirely.

This avoids any possibility of a crash trying to resolve a resource while in the wrong configuration. See the [Providing Resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#Compatibility) documentation for more info.

Answer (score 3):

update entry for your activity in `AndroidManifest.xml` to force use of landscape

```
<activity        
   android:name="MyActivity"
   android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

Comment: I don't think Android will be ok not finding that folder. Just keep it empty, it's not that much a problem of application size.

Comment: @LucaNicoletti Wrong. That folder is totally optional. If missing, it will use the current orientation. Which can be forced.